# Conditionally count the number of times a column in a row is one of a number of values?

Tags: mysql

Is there a native to MySQL method for building counts based on column value? My use case is as follows:

I have machines, employees, and products. Each time an employee interacts with one machine and one product, an entry is generated in a separate table called entries. Each machine has a type corresponding to the values of a table called stage. I want to use a complex query in order to count the number of times an employee has completed each stage.

**My schema for each table is here:**
entries table:

[image]

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `entries`;
CREATE TABLE `entries` (
  `Employee` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `Product` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Machine` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DateTimeAdded` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `TimeTaken` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The amount of time taken for each entry to be processed'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `entries` (`Employee`, `Product`, `Machine`, `DateTimeAdded`, `TimeTaken`) VALUES
(1, '365', 1, '2020-11-13 11:55:15', 0.0094444444444444),
(1, '365', 5, '2020-11-13 11:55:49', 2.6069444444444),
(1, '1', 1, '2020-11-13 14:21:45', 0.019722222222222),
(1, '4', 1, '2020-11-13 14:22:56', 0.071388888888889),
(1, '2', 1, '2020-11-13 14:27:13', 0.066666666666667),
(1, '3', 1, '2020-11-13 14:31:13', 0.064722222222222),
(1, '2', 5, '2020-11-13 14:32:14', 0.015555555555556),
(1, '2', 8, '2020-11-13 14:33:10', 0.080277777777778),
(1, '3', 2, '2020-11-13 14:35:06', 0.0036111111111111),
(1, '4', 2, '2020-11-13 14:35:19', 0.012777777777778),
(1, '4', 6, '2020-11-13 14:36:05', 0.18944444444444),
(1, '1', 5, '2020-11-13 14:43:08', 115.66777777778),
(1, '4', 9, '2020-11-13 14:47:27', 0.012222222222222),
(1, '2', 9, '2020-11-13 14:48:11', 115.58861111111),
(1, '1', 1, '2020-11-18 10:23:12', NULL),
(1, '2', 1, '2020-11-18 10:23:30', 2.8641666666667),
(1190, '2', 5, '2020-11-18 13:15:21', 0.01),
(1190, '2', 8, '2020-11-18 13:15:57', 0.28361111111111),
(1190, '6', 14, '2020-11-18 13:26:36', NULL);
```

User (employee) table:
[image]

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `Username` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `DateHired` datetime NOT NULL,
  `JobRole` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `user` (`Username`, `Password`, `DateHired`, `JobRole`, `Status`, `FirstName`, `LastName`) VALUES
(1, '1', '2020-02-02 12:22:11', 'Manager', 'FullTime', 'Manager', 'User'),
(10, '1', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'Viewer', 'fulltime', 'Viewer', 'User'),
(1190, '1', '2020-08-04 00:00:00', 'Employee', 'partTime', 'Employee', 'User'),
(1198, '67f7a304c32875eadc0f', '2020-11-19 00:00:00', 'Employee', '', 'Eric', 'Wise');
```

Stage table:

[image]

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stage`;
CREATE TABLE `stage` (
  `StageID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `StageName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `stage` (`StageID`, `StageName`) VALUES
(1, 'Pre-Inspection'),
(2, 'Pre-Washing (Jig-Washer)'),
(3, 'Stripping (Shot)'),
(4, 'Stripping (Liquid)'),
(5, 'WPC-SKH'),
(6, 'WPC-Ceramic'),
(7, 'Pre-Lapping (SMAP)'),
(8, 'Pre-Lapping (AERO)'),
(9, 'Pre-Lapping (Hand Lapping)'),
(10, 'Pre-Washing (F1 Clean Washer)'),
(11, 'Coating (M1) - Set/Disassemble'),
(12, 'Coating (M2) - Set/Disassemble'),
(13, 'Coating (M3) - Set/Disassemble'),
(14, 'Post-Inspection'),
(15, 'Post-Lapping (SMAP)'),
(16, 'Post-Lapping (AERO)'),
(17, 'Post-Lapping (Hand Lapping)'),
(18, 'Final Inspection'),
(19, 'Packing/Shipping');
```

Machine table:

[image]

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `machine`;
CREATE TABLE `machine` (
  `MachineID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NumberOfTimesUsed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MachineType` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HoursUptime` double UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'the number of hours a machine has been used',
  `LastMaintenanceDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MachineAutoTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The time a machine runs without human interaction'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `machine` (`MachineID`, `NumberOfTimesUsed`, `MachineType`, `HoursUptime`, `LastMaintenanceDate`, `MachineAutoTime`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'Pre-Inspection', 2.8641666666667, '2020-11-13', 0),
(2, 0, 'Pre-Washing (Jig-Washer)', 45.8408333333339, NULL, 0),
(3, 0, 'Stripping (Shot)', 25.089722222222672, NULL, 0),
(4, 0, 'Stripping (Liquid)', 0, NULL, 0),
(5, 0, 'WPC-SKH', 0, '2020-11-18', 0),
(6, 0, 'WPC-Ceramic', 0.18944444444444, NULL, 0),
(7, 0, 'Pre-Lapping (SMAP)', 0, NULL, 0),
(8, 0, 'Pre-Lapping (AERO)', 0.363888888888888, NULL, 0),
(9, 0, 'Pre-Lapping (Hand Lapping)', 115.62416666666556, '2020-11-08', 0),
(10, 0, 'Pre-Washing (F1 Clean Washer)', 0, NULL, 0),
(11, 0, 'Coating (M1) - Set/Disassemble', 0, NULL, 0),
(12, 0, 'Coating (M2) - Set/Disassemble', 0, NULL, 0),
(13, 0, 'Coating (M3) - Set/Disassemble', 0, NULL, 0),
(14, 0, 'Post-Inspection', 0, NULL, 0),
(15, 0, 'Post-Lapping (SMAP)', 23.692222222222, NULL, 0),
(16, 0, 'Post-Lapping (AERO)', 0, NULL, 0),
(17, 0, 'Post-Lapping (Hand Lapping)', 0, NULL, 0),
(18, 0, 'Final Inspection', 0, NULL, 0),
(19, 0, 'Packing/Shipping', 44.83916666666622, NULL, 0);
```

**The logic is as follows:**

> Pull the stage names from the table
>
> pull the machine from the entry table where ID is the employee I am looking for
>
> loop through the entry results, adding counts to variables based on if MachineType is equal to StageName

I wanted to know if there is a native way to do this in MySQL or if I need to pull all the information and do the counting inside of the back-end server code.

So far my train of thought is to use some sort of case statement inside of the SQL statement. I am very new to SQL, so I am not sure where to begin on formatting such a query. Does this sound like the right direction?

The expected results are as follows:

```
+----------+----------------+--------------------------+------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------+------------------+
| Employee | Pre-Inspection | Pre-Washing (Jig-Washer) | Stripping (Shot) | Stripping (Liquid) | WPC-SKH | WPC-Ceramic | Pre-Lapping (SMAP) | Pre-Lapping (AERO) | Pre-Lapping (Hand Lapping) | Pre-Washing (F1 Clean Washer) | Coating (M1) - Set/Disassemble | Coating (M2) - Set/Disassemble | Coating (M3) - Set/Disassemble | Post-Inspection | Post-Lapping (SMAP) | Post-Lapping (AERO) | Post-Lapping (Hand Lapping) | Final Inspection | Packing/Shipping |
+----------+----------------+--------------------------+------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 1        | 7              | 2                        | 0                | 0                  | 3       | 0           | 0                  | 1                  | 2                          | 0                             | 0                              | 0                              | 0                              | 0               | 0                   | 0                   | 0                           | 0                | 0                |
+----------+----------------+--------------------------+------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 1190     | 1              | 0                        | 0                | 0                  | 1       | 0           | 0                  | 1                  | 0                          | 0                             | 0                              | 0                              | 0                              | 1               | 0                   | 0                   | 0                           | 0                | 0                |
+----------+----------------+--------------------------+------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Pictures are not useful. Provide CREATE TABLE scripts, INSERT INTO scripts with sample data and desired output for this data.

Comment: @Akina I have editted to add the sql for tables and the current working test data. I will work on manually determining the output from this dataset and edit the question again shortly to add the expected outcome. Sorry for the poorly formatted question!

Comment: I have added the expected result as well.